# Flicker in snake game develope in java

Tags: java, 2d-games

I have developed a snake game in Java. The problem is that I see a flicker while the game is running. Can anyone please inform me why this is happening and direct me to a possible solution?

The code for the game can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Pce8JUP6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [double buffering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)?

Looking at your code, what about the following being a potential cause

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer.

Thread.sleep(1000) used to stop the current Thread i.e. While loop for 1000 milliseconds

Comment: You will put the thread managing the Frame to sleep for at least a second (it could be more because after one second the thread only becomes Runnable again, it still needs to be actually scheduled). You can see the state change diagram for threads here http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/life-cycle-of-threads.shtml. While your thread is asleep no drawing takes place and hence you get flicker.

Comment: so what can I do to remove this flicking.

Comment: Try placing your game logic and display logic in separate threads